# Is it possible to store a Map object in conversationData databag?

Tags: botframework

Is it possible to store a `Map` object inside a `conversationData` databag using the Botframework SDK for Nodejs?

The map could be `<string,boolean>` and like that.

Thanks,
Pranav

Answer (score 0):

You can set fields within your bot code in [conversationData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#storage-containers) arbitrarily, and this also includes maps. So something like:

```
//example, but obviously this map can come from anywhere and have its values set arbitrarily as well.
var someMap = new Map([["field1", 1], ["field2", 23], ["field3", 11515]]); 

session.conversationData.internalMap = someMap;
```

Will work just fine and store the data for use for the duration of the conversation.